# Splice item of array and of all its references (children array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know if it's possible to slice (or delete an item) of an array and transmit this change to its children. Its children having only part of the items of the parent.

Meaning, I have:

```
let myArr = [{number: 1}, {number: 2}, {number: 3}, {number: 4}];
let partRef = [];

for(let int = 0; int < myArr.length - 1; int++){
    partRef.push(myArr[int]);
}
// delete here item 2 from myArr and it gets transmitted to partRef
```

What I would like is that when I `myArr.splice(1, 1)` (or any delete function), the `number 2` also disappears from `partRef`.

The following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/we033mK6S8iYaXxw9Lt7?p=preview) shows the real case with Angular 2 and its classes (everything happens in class1 and class2). You have to open your console to see.

Comment: Only if object is referring other object, this will happen...

Comment: @Rayon can you be more explicit?

Comment: Then why did you copy the array? Just forget the whole loop and do `partRef =myArr;` and your done. Now `myArr.splice(1, 1)` will happen in the *shared* array.

Comment: @trincot Please read carefully the question, I don't copy all the array `myArr.length - 1`. I've intentionally omitted one item because, in my code I use a filter. I just wanted to make it simpler to understand!

Comment: have you considered `.filter()` ? or do you need to keep references to your arrays ?

Comment: @ncohen, I actually thought that the `myArr.length-1` was a mistake in your code. But if that is intentional, then what you want is impossible. The arrays occupy two different array locations. You cannot define them (in JavaScript) as one being a part of the other. So your solution should be to write a custom function that performs the `splice` on both arrays, and you never call `splice` directly, but use that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `partRef` is a different array, distinct from `myArr`, this is not possible. But read on...

In JavaScript there are some ways to have views on the same memory location, using [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), but it seems not possible to use that as solution in this context.

I will propose the use of a [`proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to achieve the effect. The idea is that you trap any `myArr.splice` call and apply it equally to the `partRef` array.

But first I should note that the loop you have really comes down to:

```
let partRef = myArr.slice(0, 3);
```

Here is the proxy-based solution:

```js
let myArr = [{number: 1}, {number: 2}, {number: 3}, {number: 4}];
let partRef = myArr.slice(0, 3);

// Our custom version of `splice`. It does the normal `splice`, but
// also performs it on `partRef`:
function mySplice () {
    [].splice.apply(partRef, arguments);
    return [].splice.apply(this, arguments);
}

// Redefine `myArr` as a proxy on itself, and trap any call to `splice`
myArr = new Proxy(myArr, {
    get: function (obj, prop) {
        // If `splice` is accessed, then use `mySplice` instead. All other
        // properties are not influenced.
        return (prop === 'splice') ? mySplice : obj[prop];
    }
});

// Test it.
myArr.splice(1, 1);
console.log(partRef);
```

The nice thing about such a "proxied" object is that cannot (easily) be distinguished from the original. For instance `Array.isArray(myArr)` will return `true`.